# K in SKI combinator calculus: why doesn't it take one parameter since it ignores its second?

Tags: logic, combinatory-logic

In the SKI combinator calculus, Kxy returns the constant function which always returns x. Since y is always ignored, why not just define K as having a single parameter, namely, x? What is the purpose of having a variable y which is guaranteed to be ignored by K? I'm guessing that there would be some deleterious effect on the system if one were to omit y from the definition of K, but I can't figure out what that would be.

EDIT: For example, one can define K in terms of a simpler combinator, like, say:

$Jx := () \implies x$ (in JS anonymous function style). I.e., $J$ returns a thunk of $x$ just like $K$ does, but without the vestigial second parameter.

Then define $Kxy := Jx$. At that point the $SKI$ calculus is just the $SJ$ calculus since $K$ can be retrieved from $J$ and $I$ is definable in terms of $S$ and $K$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would help to think about it comparing to functions:

$K$ can be interpreted as the function with two arguments that returns the first. In Python, it would be

```python
def K(x, y):
    return x
```

$I$ is the identity function. It can be written as:

```python
def I(x):
    return x
```

Are those Python functions equivalent? No. To prove that the existence of $K$ is necessary, you can actually prove that $I$ can be expressed with only $S$ and $K$, but not the converse : $I = SKx$. Indeed, $SKxy = Ky(xy) = y = Iy$.

From a mathematical point of view: you need projections to do some computations. I am sure that you agree that working with multiple arguments. However, you sometimes need to only keep some of them. This is the same reason one of the basic operations of [general recursive functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_recursive_function#Definition) is the projection. In SK-calculus, you can use the $S$ rule to do a projection on a different argument.

Comment: Thanks @Nathaniel. And I'm wondering if I understand $K$ correctly. I thought it was a higher order function and returned  a function, so that calls like "$Ky(xy)$" would go through.

Comment: There is always two points of view, depending on [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying): you can see $K$ either as a function with two arguments, or as a function that takes one argument and returns a function that takes one argument.

Comment: @Nathaniel Do you have a reference that contains a proof that the converse isn't possible?

Comment: @SamEzeh Sorry, I have not. My guess is that it can be done by induction on the size of an expression using only $S$ and $I$.

Comment: The $K$ combinator is higher-order, since it can accept functions as argument and return them. However there is an isomorphism between $(A \times B) \rightarrow C$ and $A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)$. This isomorphism is the essence of many constructions in functional programming and logic, and studied abstractly in [cartesian closed categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category).